# String to ByteBuffer

Tags: java, строки

Мне нужно в сокет отправить строку. При этом, в пакете вначале должно идти длина пакета в байтах.

Пишу такой код

```
private static final CharsetEncoder encoder =
  Charset.forName("UTF-8").newEncoder();
......
String data = .........
CharBuffer buf = CharBuffer.wrap(data);
ByteBuffer outBuf;
synchronized (encoder) {
    outBuf = encoder.encode(buf);
}

outBuf.rewind();
ByteBuffer bufLen = ByteBuffer.allocate(Integer.BYTES);
bufLen.putInt(outBuf.remaining());
bufLen.rewind();
attachment.write(bufLen, (att1) ->
    att1.write(outBuf, (att2) -> att2.read(this::readCompleted))
);
```

Т.е. вначале получаю в буфере содержимое строки, потом в отдельный буфер записываю длину, потом отправляю длину, а при успешной отправке отправляю сами данные.

Вопрос, можно ли как-то записать строку в существующий буфер? Про схему

```
encoder.reset();
encoder.encode(CharBuffer.wrap(data), buffer, true);
encoder.flush(buffer);
```

знаю. Но тогда нужно изначально выделить место под `buffer`. А как его корректно и **быстро** посчитать - не знаю.

Или оставить как есть, с отправкой двух пакетов?

Comment: `String data = .........` - это что такое?

Comment: @RomanC Присвоение некоторых строковых данных